# Inserting subclass types(Integer/String) into superclass types(Object) in ArrayList

Tags: java, generics

I am learning generics.

I tried below code:

For HashSet

```
Set<Object> setOfAnyType = new HashSet<Object>();
setOfAnyType.add(1);
setOfAnyType.add("abc");
```

But When I try same thing in ArrayList of type Object and try to insert integer and String it gives me compile time error why?.Please guide.

```
    List<Object> superArray=new ArrayList<Object>();
    superArray.put(1);
    superArray.put("abc");
```

Comment: When you need help with a compile error, make sure to post the error message itself and indicate to which line it refers.

Comment: Also, whenever you get some compiler error related to some class of Java API, first take a look at the API, whether you are using it correctly. You will certainly be able to solve the problem most of the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `put` is undefined for `List`, you can use:

```
superArray.add(1);
superArray.add("Sakina");
```